# position on ListView is always empty

Tags: android, listview, position

i'm playing around with a piece of code i found on the web and i'm trying to add a click listener to the listview and get the position of the item. however the position is always empty for some reason. here is my code:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


            Log.v("position", position); //POSITION IS ALWAYS EMPTY

            Intent i = new Intent(Example.this, ShowReleases.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
        }
    });
```

i have also added the complete code just in case:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Example extends Activity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    public Bitmap placeholder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = getTweets("android", 1);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);
        listView.setAdapter(new TweetItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, tweets));         

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


                Log.v("position", position); //POSITION IS ALWAYS EMPTY

                Intent i = new Intent(Example.this, ShowReleases.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
            }
        });
    }


    public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String searchTerm, int page) {
        String searchUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@" + searchTerm;
        Log.v("searchUrl", searchUrl);

        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

        HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        String responseBody = null;
        try{
            responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
            jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;

        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.v("TEST","Exception1: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        JSONArray arr = null;

        try {
            Object j = jsonObject.get("results");
            arr = (JSONArray)j;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, "JSON Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.v("TEST","Exception2: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        for(Object t : arr) {
            Tweet tweet = new Tweet(
                    ((JSONObject)t).get("from_user").toString(),
                    ((JSONObject)t).get("text").toString(),
                    ((JSONObject)t).get("profile_image_url").toString(),
                    ((JSONObject)t).get("id").toString()
                    );
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }

        return tweets;
    }   

    /** Classes **/

    public class Tweet {
        public String username;
        public String message;
        public String image_url;
        public String post_id;
        public Boolean usernameSet = false;
        public Boolean messageSet = false;
        public Boolean imageSet = false;
        public Bitmap avatar;

        public Tweet(String username, String message, String url, String post_id) {
            this.username = username;
            this.message = message;
            this.image_url = url;
            this.post_id = post_id;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance
robert

Comment: try "getApplicationContext()" instead this at listView.setAdapter. I think its adapter class problem

Comment: its not returning anything, all i see in the logcat is an empty field instead of a number

Comment: are you actually receiving anything in array list? have you tried logging the things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured out what was wrong. i had to convert the position var to a string using String.valueOf(position);
here is the complete code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.v("position", String.valueOf(position));
        Intent i = new Intent(Example.this, ShowReleases.class);
        i.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(position));
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First Check the list Size, i used the same thing in my application its working fine.
in the first actvity i passed like this

```
 in.putExtra(id, position);
```

in the second activty i wrote like this to get the data

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
arg=extras.getInt(id);
System.out.println("Position:"+arg);
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. i'm new to android. can you explain this a bit more? it would be great if you could post some code for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

you can see constructor AdapterView(Context context) so use get application context.
Or visit this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html

Hope this will help you

Comment: hello, can you explain this a bit more? i'm new to android and i don't understand a lot. can you give me a code example? thanks in advance

Comment: Sure Robs, See here AdapterView is one class which you are extends in TweetItemAdapter. Now if you use this then it will take context of Adapter class while your need your activity class context so you need to use getapplicationcontext(). this will give you your application context. If you want then you can read on android dev guid. We have very good documentation for android SDK. Hope this will help you.